# Python Inline Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm attempting to interleave a value into a list.

```
interleave(1, ['A', 'B', 'C']) -> [1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C']
```

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, but I thought [more_itertools.interleave](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.interleave) would be the most readable. However to use this function I need to create a generator that yields `1` forever. Clearly this can be done with

```py
def gen1():
    while True:
        yield 1
```

but this feels more complicated than necessary.

Is there an elegant way to replace `...` in the snippet below to create an inline generator such that

```py
res = more_itertools.interleave(..., ['A', 'B', 'C'])
assert list(res) == [1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C']
```

`... = (1 for _ in ['A', 'B', 'C'])` clearly works, but I wouldn't call it elegant.

Comment: That generator does not yield 1 forever... It yields 1 once... Anyway, you want `itertools.repeat(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat).  I don't know how `interleave` is implemented, but you can do the same thing with `chain` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(repeat(1), ['A', 'B', 'C']))))
# [1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension like this:

```
def interleave(value, lst):
    return [j for i in lst for j in (value, i)]
```

So that `interleave(1, ['A', 'B', 'C'])` returns:

```
[1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def interleave(a,list1):
    newlist=[]
    for x in list1:newlist.extend([a,x])
    return newlist
print(interleave(1,['A','B','C']))
```

prints

```
[1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C']
```